# Йотування в словах іншомовного походження

Tags: вживання-слів, правопис, граматика, іншомовні-слова, словотворення

Чи маємо йотувати літери в наступних словах та як саме: нацІОнальність, асоцІАція, трАЕкторія тощо?

Answer (score 2):

Підхід до цього змінювався в різні часи… Відразу зазначу, йотувати «о» не пропонували ніколи (тобто *національність*, а не, наприклад, *наційональність*). Але от щодо «а», «е», «у»…

[Харківський правопис](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81) (це 1920-ті роки) пропонував йотувати всі ці три звуки (див. також [«Варіант чи варіянт»](/q/870)):

> Після всіх пригол. перед голосн. та **й**, при чім чуже *ia* передаємо через **ія**, *іе* — через **іє**, *iu* — через **ію** (у загальних іменниках), але *іо* через — **іо**: *матер**ія́**л*, *істо́р**ія***, *ко́п**ія***, *Аз**ія***, *соц**ія**лі́зм*, *спец**ія́**льний*, *мін**ія**тю́рний*, *пал**ія**ти́в*, *амон**ія́**к*, *д**ія**ле́кт* і т. ін.; *авд**іє́**нція*, *г**іє́**на*, *кл**іє́**нт*, *п**іє**те́т*, *Тр**іє́**ст* і т. ін.; *тр**ію́**мф*, *тр**ію**мвіра́т*, *ра́д**ію**с*, *конси́л**ію**м*, *ме́д**ію**м*, але *К**іу**-С**іу*** і т. ін.; *ембр**іо́**н*, *гел**іо**тро́п*, *б**іо**ско́п*, *соц**іо**ло́гія*, *акс**іо́**ма*, *Онта́р**іо***; *крите́р**і**й*, *ра́д**і**й* і т. ін.
>
> Але іноді **і** перед голосними скорочується: *сер**йо́**зний*, *кур**йо́**з*, *бар**’є́**р*, *ар**’є**рґа́рд*, *кар**’є́**ра*, *прем**’є́**р*, *п**’є**деста́ль*, *п**’є́**са*, *Ф**’ю́**ме* — див. іще [§ 68](//r2u.org.ua/node/245).

Але в 1930-х роках радянська влада назвала цей правопис «націоналістичним», скасувала (причому його укладачі зазнали репресій; щоправда репресій частково зазнали й укладачі наступного правопису; див. також [розстріляне відродження](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F)), і було впроваджено [правопис 1933 року](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81_1933_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83), який фактично:

- скасовував більшість випадків йотування «а» (не в закінченнях): *асоц**іа́**ція*, *вар**іа́**нт*, *соц**іа́**льний* (але *А́з**ія***, *істо́р**ія***, *ко́п**ія***);
- скасовував деякі випадки йотування «е», зокрема *пр**ое́**кт*, але лишав більшість: *г**іє́**на*, *кл**іє́**нт*, *тр**ає**кто́рія*;
- скасовував більшість випадків йотування «у» (не в закінченнях): *конси́л**іу**м*, *ме́д**іу**м*, *ра́д**іу**с* (але *А́з**ію***, *істо́р**ію***, *ко́п**ію***).

Цей аспект залишався незмінним до 2019 року (якщо не брати до уваги [проєкт 1999 року](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%94%D0%BA%D1%82_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%83_1999_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83), який так не було ухвалено), коли [новий правопис](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81_2019_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83):

- зробив певні кроки назустріч харківському, зокрема повернулося йотування «е» в слові *пр**оє́**кт* і похідних від нього (*пр**оє́**кція*, *пр**оє́**ктивний* тощо);
- але лишив «а» і «у» у більшості випадків без йотування, як у правописі 1933-го.

Отже, згідно з **чинним** правописом:

- «а» зазвичай не йотується (окрім, звісно, закінчень): *асоц**іа́**ція*, *вар**іа́**нт*, *соц**іа́**льний*;
- «е» зазвичай йотується: *г**іє́**на*, *кл**іє́**нт*, *тр**ає**кто́рія*, *пр**оє́**кт*;
- «у» зазвичай не йотується (окрім, звісно, закінчень): *конси́л**іу**м*, *ме́д**іу**м*, *ра́д**іу**с*
- («о» очевидно не йотується).

(Утім частина української спільноти свідомо йотує частіше, ніж це рекомендує чинний правопис, зокоема послідовники харківського правопису йотують «а», «е» і «у» в більшості випадків: *асоц**ія́**ція*, *вар**ія́**нт*, *соц**ія́**льний*; *г**іє́**на*, *кл**іє́**нт*, *тр**ає**кто́рія*, *пр**оє́**кт*; *конси́л**ію**м*, *ме́д**ію**м*, *ра́д**ію**с*.)

Comment: < *йотувати «о» не пропонували ніколи* > В простонародній _шпійон_, _війола_, _чемпійон_, _радійо_ ітп існують. Щодо правил, треʼ пошукати. Зараз, правда, чомусь переважно використовують для неґатівного окрасу, щось подібне з правильним _нарід_ проти чинного _народ_.

Comment: @stegetsj, згоден. (А хіба варіант «нарід» використовують з негативним окрасом?)

Comment: З того що бачу, так — поглянь нп. на вираз _мудрий нарід_, котрий навіть в один [словник](https://myslovo.com/?dictionary=мудрий-нарід) потрапив.